# faster and better way of making 2d platform?

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to make a 2d platform with WPF by using various shapes classes, such as ellipse and rectangle. What I learned is that these shapes are not the most amazing resources i can use. They are slow. I want to have many different objects such as bullet enemy, hero, blocks and so on. So i concluded using canvas tool is not the best option I have.
I would like to know the other faster ways of rendering images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DirectX 2D and XNA 2D are high-level interfaces (compared to controlling the graphic adapters directly) that allow you to create fast 2D and 3D graphics animations. Tutorials, which helped me a lot, are [Riemer's 2D & 3D XNA Tutorials](http://www.riemers.net/).

Comment: Depending on what you want to do in the future (stay mobile, stay with desktop apps, create/port metro style win 8 apps) you should use XNA or not. XNA seems to be dead for usage in Win8 Metro so far (ANX http://anxframework.codeplex.com/ might be a promising upcoming alternative for future development but is in an early alpha stage and not ready for production use). I would recommend XNA only if you want to develop win phone 7 and desktop apps.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look for a game engine instead of coding all the graphics related stuff by yourself. Have a look at this list:

http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/Game_Engines

Also if you want to go more low level and only intereste in the drawing aspects (no physics engine etc.) SharpDX and SlimDX might be options because you can call them through c#.

http://slimdx.org/

http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/